# Databinding to a property within an object in the DataContext in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, data-binding, window

In my application I'm databinding to a ViewModel which is just a class with the properties I need, which gets set as the screen's DataContext. This has worked fine for individual properties, but when I try and databind to a property within an object in my view model, no values are displayed.

I.e: for the view model:

```
public class ViewModel {
    int someNumber { get { return 6; } }
    string someValue { get { return "Some Text"; } }
    SomeObject myObject = new SomeObject { anotherVal = "More text" };
}
```

Using `Text="{Binding someNumber}"` or `Text="{Binding someValue}"` works fine, but `Text={Binding myObject.anotherVal}"` doesn't. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

(myObject is set as an instantiated SomeObject btw, I just showed it like that to demonstrate the property I am after)

Comment: Can we see the contents of `SomeObject`?

Comment: `public SomeObject { string anotherVal { get; set; } }` thats about it

Comment: I presume `anotherVal` is public?

Comment: There are a lot of "I am not really doing that, only in this example..." comments throughout this question. My guess is that it is something trivial. Start form scratch, new project, build out a simple ViewModel and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding to `myObject.anotherVal` or just `myObject`? Your binding statement should look something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding myObject.anotherVal}" />
```

Comment: Yeah trying to bind to anotherVal, and thats the code I've used but it's not working

Comment: @Jordan, Are you really setting the value in your view model's constructor as you have in your example, or are you doing `InitializeComponents()` on your view, then later setting `myObject`? If it's the latter, you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your view model...otherwise the view will never realize that anything changed on the object.

Comment: No I'm not, sorry I tried to write a stripped down example of my problem so it was clear, but I think I've left more ambiguity than anything! The view model is created first, so all values are set, and then it is set as the screens datacontext when the screen loads

Comment: Well, it should work then. Are you absolutely positive you don't have a misspelling in your binding statement? The compiler will not check spelling in markup for you like it does for code.

Comment: Yeah definitely no spelling mistakes, I've gone over and over it to be sure!